# How to correctly use jQuery remove in this case

Tags: jquery

I have the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ycysD/1/ in which i try to remove an element of the DOM using a funcion, also I have two events that execute this function, both do the same thing however in one casi it fails

Sorry for the english and tell me if you need some other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is caused by a conflict in the code. When the close button is clicked you both create and remove a new `.media-list-display`.

```
 _close.bind('click',function(e){
//This line removes the .media-list-display div when 
//the close button is clicked

$('.media-list a').live('click',function(e){
//This line adds a new .media-list-display div when any `<a>` 
//inside .media-list is clicked.
```

The problem is that the close button is also an `<a>` inside `.media-list` so when it is clicked it triggers both events creating an endless loop of removing and creating.

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ycysD/2/) out with alerts on the conflicting parts.

Answer (score 3):

No idea if this is the correct behavior, but here's what I changed:

```
function closeMediaList(what){
    $('.media-list-display').fadeOut(function(){
        what.remove();
    });
};
```

`what` is the object which gets removed, so instead of just calling:

```
closeMedialList();
```

You call:

```
closeMediaList($(this));
```

Here's a demo of what the changes did: http://jsfiddle.net/t4u33/

Comment: If you check with firebug there still are some .media-list-display nodes after the remove... and also why is this behavior ocurring?

Comment: See my edit: http://jsfiddle.net/t4u33/1/. Your original script worked AFAICT, so it must be something with Firebug, as on Chrome, that element disappears.

Comment: This last fiddle does work, however you make 2 searches to the DOM, why is $(this) not working in this case? also i checked the previous fiddle in Chrome and it does have the .media-list-display nodes,alebit they're hidden

Comment: I really have no idea. It didn't work when I tried it, so I tried using the selector and it did.